# How to add Jquery plugin to Drupal?

Tags: javascript

Should I just paste the code in the main template file, or is there any other recommended way of attaching new Jquery plugins in Drupal 7?

Comment: What kind of JQuery plugin are you looking to use and why?  Normally adding any type of Javascript is added using the function `drupal_add_js` (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js).

Comment: Qtip - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/download/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is just to add it on your theme's .info file:

```
scripts[] = js/my_jquery_plugin.js
```

The only exception is if you are adding an external resource (CDN/hosted script), in which case you should use drupal_add_js(), as explained by Jamie Hollern

Comment: But the chrome console alter me: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @Alex I got a dumb question. I know Drupal is using jquery library. Let say I'm addint the "back to top" funtion by using the idea you have "scripts[] = js/back_to_top.js" in theme.info. Do I also need to add the jquery file(like jquery v1.9, v1.11)?

Comment: @CocoSkin you should be fine

Comment: Actually - no. That does not always work. Two examples:
1) scripts[] = js/jquery.hoverintent.js 
2) scripts[] = js/jquery.scrollme.js

Comment: Generally not a good way to do it. How do you control which pages it's loaded on? Use `drupal_add_library()`

Answer (score 12):

Drupal has Jquery packaged with it.

To add a js file you can use drupal_add_js in the way descibed in other posts.

This will work in simple cases, but if you start to have plugins which depend on other plugins. you may want to look at the [libraries api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7). I expect in time modules will be created to support popular libraries, there are some for JQuery ui built in see [system_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_library/7).

In this example to inclued the jQuery ui.accordion module you can use [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7)

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

This will make sure the js is included along with the CSS and any libraries which depend upon it. It will also make sure that the libraries are only included once.

*If you say which library you are using I can provide sample code for how to define it*

So first create a module to define the library (call it qtip) and upload the module to a js folder underneath the module folder

then implement [hook_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7)

```
function qtip_library() (
 $libraries['qTip'] = array(
    'title' => 'qTip', 
    'website' => 'http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/', 
    'version' => '1.0.0-rc3', 
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'qtip') . '/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0.min.js' => array(),
    ),
    'dependencies' => array(
      array('system', 'jquery'),
    ),
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Then to add the file put in your code

```
drupal_add_library('qtip', 'qtip');
```

This may be overkill for a simple library but if you have to manage a large number of libraries over multiple sites and themes it does make life much easier.

Comment: Thanks, I am using QTip library - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

Answer (score 5):

If you want to load script only on some pages (not all) you can add it trough your template.php file. Just add code similar to this:

```
function YourTheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

 $node = $variables['node'];
if (!empty($node) && ($node->nid == 983)
 // here you can esily add more pages
) {

drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/ui.core.js');
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.js');
drupal_add_js('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/ui/ui.progressbar.js');

drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/themes/redmond/ui.progressbar.css');
drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/themes/redmond/ui.core.css');
drupal_add_css('sites/all/libraries/jquery.ui/themes/redmond/ui.theme.css');
 }
}
```

I only tested this in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a JavaScript file to the theme you use in the Drupal site, by adding a `script[] =` line in the .info file of the theme you are using. I would consider this case only if you are using a customized theme, or a modified version of an existing theme that has been renamed; I would not suggest to do it if you are using, for example, Garland. Doing it in such cases would mean to lose all changes all times the theme is updated, or to copy the updated theme files, and then re-apply the same changes applied to the previous version of the files; if the change is only adding a `script[]` line, then the change is minimal, and it could be worth doing it, but it would also mean the JavaScript files are not added in the directory containing the theme files, or you should add the JavaScript files every time the theme is updated.

As alternative, you can create a custom module, or add code to an existing custom module you are already using for that site.
The pro is that the JavaScript files would be added to every theme is set as default, or administration theme, without the need to change all the themes that are enabled on the site, and that users can select for themselves.

As already reported in another answer, [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) is the hook you should implement. I will add that [`hook_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) is the new hook added in Drupal 7 for Javascript files like jQuery plug-ins.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Js Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module to add scripts directly in Drupal admin panel. Alternatively you can use [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function to add your js file to your page.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need, I will choose your answer as best, but I want to see if other solutions exist first ;)

Comment: you can add this line to your theme.info script[] = 'path to your file' that is one method but with this method the js will get loaded on all your pages which is normally not a good practice. With the above two methods you can add the js on exactly those pages you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple custom module and add it that way.  The code would be similar to the following:

```
MYMODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/FILE.js');
}
```

Comment: custom module for adding JQuery? Seriously?

Comment: only if it is external, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use in `YOURTHEME_preprocess_theme()` if you want apply logical condition:

`drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme','your_theme').'/js/yourplugin.js');`

and add also in yourtheme.info file:

`scripts[] = js/yourplugin.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Context module, install Context Add Assets.  Set up a global context, or a specific context, and add a new reaction to add the JS asset by path or by module.

No coding required.

Comment: Thanks! This has the advantage that you can limit libraries to specific paths, yet no coding is required.

Comment: But for jQuery plugins like textext.js which include 5 CSS and 5 JS files on average, it's still lots of work.

Answer (score 1):

There are many external libraries which need to be included nowadays.

Putting them all under the theme's js directory is not always desirable since sometimes those libraries are composed of multiple js files and multiple css files.

I ended up using the `libraries_get_path` function of the libraries module to take their paths from the sites/all/libraries dir:

Here is how I added selected files which relate to textext.js:

```
<?php 
function MYMODULE_init() {

  // Add jQuery library to a specific page.
  if (arg(0) == 'messages' && arg(1) == 'new') {
    // Add the jQuery TextExt library ( http://textextjs.com/ )
    $libdir = libraries_get_path('jquery-textext');
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.core.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.core.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.tags.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.autocomplete.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.suggestions.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.filter.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.focus.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.prompt.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.ajax.js");
    drupal_add_js("$libdir/src/js/textext.plugin.arrow.js");

    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.core.css");
    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.plugin.tags.css");
    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.plugin.autocomplete.css");
    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.plugin.focus.css");
    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.plugin.prompt.css");
    drupal_add_css("$libdir/src/css/textext.plugin.arrow.css");
  }

} ?>
```

I would love to hear if there is an external repository in which all of those libraries are predefined so I won't have to define them each manually.

Comment: How do you add pages in it?

Answer (score 0):

I recomment you to load jQuery from the pupblic Google CDN. Check this link for more info:
http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery .Just make sure you don't load the same script multiple times in your site.

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me, no need to create a module for a jQuery plugin or install one -
in my template.php I added:

```
function YOURTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript){
    // overwriting for newer jQuery version
    $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = path_to_theme() . '/assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.js';
    // also the min...
    $javascript['misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js']['data'] = path_to_theme() . '/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js';
    // here I add the library (jQuery plugin) to resolve an error -> $.browser.msie undefined
    $javascript[path_to_theme() . '/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js'] = array(   
        "group" => -100,
        "weight" => -18.990,
        "version" => "1.1.0",
        "every_page" => true,
        "type" =>   "file",
        "scope" => "header",
        "cache" => true,
        "defer" => false,
        "preprocess" => true,
        "data" =>  path_to_theme() . '/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js',
    );

}
```

Answer (score -4):

another way is to add the following code to the page.tpl.php file
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'path/to/your/plugin') . '/plugin.js', 'file');

Comment: Adding code directly to templates is considered bad practice.

Comment: " 
Adding code directly to templates is considered bad practice" ... so the SQL injector module is the best practice then?

Comment: Quite a few of the other ways mentioned could be considered good practice @BrunoVincent, it depends what level you want to attack this on (code in a theme, code in a custom module, or just install a module like js injector)

Comment: it is in some cases useful to do like this, for example you want add a javascript file conditionnaly